# Enterprise architect generate documentation - hide field with no value

Tags: rtf, enterprise-architect

Default template /fragment of EA has some kind of feature, that can hide Fields during generation, which has no value. 
If I make my own template, I don't know how to get in that future.

Example: I can have attribute with or without initial value and I don't want to generate empty label **Initial value:** if attribute has no initial value.

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide labels and formatting for blank/null values, you need to place bookmarks in the template/fragment around the text and field.

For example, if you are looking to have the field `{Att.Default}` with an optional label, you would place the bookmark `Att.Default.Start` before the label, and `Att.Default.End`, either at the end of the `{Att.Default}` or at the beginning of the next line, depending on how you want the layout to be.

Sadly, this doesn't work (at least for me) with custom fields in a custom fragment.

Comment: Nice, that was well hidden in EA's manual. Do you know of a way to show the bookmarks in a document?

Comment: I don't know any way of showing bookmarks in EA. If you go to the right-click menu and select insert and then bookmarks, you get a dialog where you can select existing bookmarks and select Go-To in order to move the cursor to the bookmark's position. In Word, you see the bookmarks as faint `[` and `]` characters, but equally you need to go to the dialog to find out which ones are which.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

eaDocX has a different approach. It has a single setting "Compact Document" which suppresses ALL fields which don't have a value.